# Fire Event Once after timeout OR other event is complete

Tags: javascript, timeout, dom-events, yui

I'm currently firing a YUI custom event that after a set of rest calls completes.  A function that disables a loading bar is subscribed to the custom event.  However, in the event that the rest call times out for some reason, I want to disable the loading bar anyway (the loading bar greys out the background, and prevents user interaction) and potentially bring up a popup saying that data could not be loaded completely.  I was thinking a simple timeout would do the trick, but I'm not sure if its the best solution.  Here is some pseudo code:

```
var event = new Yahoo...CustomEvent("abc");
event.fireOnce = true; //I don't need to fire this event multiple times
event.subscribe(hideWaitBarFunction);
window.setTimeout(event.fire(), 10000);
//rest call
event.fire();  //if rest call doesn't return after 10 seconds, hide wait bar anyway
```

In this case the event should only fire once.  Assuming for now that I don't want an error pop up, is there a better way to do this?  My Javascript/YUI knowledge is...limited.  Let me know if things need clarification.

Comment: Well, the above solution officially works.  It doesn't seem like its the cleanest, but the functionality works perfectly.  I'm still open to suggestions though as implementing this in more places would create a lot of extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using YUI 2.x, in which case the ConnectionManager's callback has a failure hook where you could plug this event firing.  Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: This question was asked over a year ago.  A solution is no longer needed.